# Method must return a value

Tags: c#

The exercise:

> Write a method that rolls up to three dice. It is passed the number of dice to roll and returns a number 1 to 6 for each of the dice rolled and zero for the dice not rolled. You will have to pass four parameters and either use the out or ref keyword or pass an Array.

Now the code i have so far:

```
    int moredice()
    {
        Random rndom = new Random();
        int nummer = rndom.Next(1, 6);
        Boolean[] Barr = { true, false, true, false, true, false };
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {

            if (Barr[nummer] == true)
                {
                return nummer;
                }

            else
                {
                return 0;
                }
        } 
    }
```

Now Visual Studio tells me I have to return something, either way.
I can't seem to return null.

And as soon as I inserted the `else` the last `i` in the for loop isn't reachable.

Is someone able to help me or give me a slight push in the right direction?

Comment: What does your question have to do with "PC interfacing 7.5"?

Comment: You have to return an integer (a whole number) because your function has the return type `int`. If you don't want to return anything, change that to voíd.

You can't return null, because null indicates a null reference, but integer is a value type that can never be null.

Comment: And why are you bothering to loop at all, given that you're returning from the loop body unconditionally? It looks like you should probably start again, to be honest. Your method currently doesn't have *any* parameters - and it's returning a single `int` when you're asked to return a value for each dice rolled.

Comment: When you call return, you will exit the method returning whatever it is you're returning. VS is telling you that you must return something, because its expecting all code paths to return something, whereas, if you weren't to get into the for loop, you'd not return anything, thus why VS is complaining.

Comment: If for some reason your code cant find a path to the two return statements then you will not be able to return an integer, As a very big push, you can find the answer to pretty much every C# error by just entering the error text into google

Comment: So as a hint, I'd make the method signature: `int[] RollDice(int diceToRoll)`

Comment: @JonSkeet It is the name of the book where this assesment is from

Comment: Thank you all for the answers so far, i'll continue trying.

Comment: based on the description I think they want `void RollDice(int diceToRoll, out int dice1, out int dice2, out int dice3)` - with the array you don't really need the zeros

Comment: @PatrickLuchies: That wasn't at *all* obvious from the question - and isn't terribly relevant.

Comment: Fyi, this method always creates the same number if called in a loop because the default constructor uses the current time as seed. Pass the `Random` instance as argument or use a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of comments being thrown at you and that is usually the case with homework assignments.

First off your assignment is asking for up to 3 dice, not more but could be less therefore your method need to understand how many dice are being rolled. For that you could write your method signature in many ways. For example you could use :

```
void rollDice(int diceCount)
{
    if(diceCount <= 0 || diceCount > 3)
         throw new ArgumentException("Dice must be between 1 to 3");
}
```

This lets you determine the amount of dice to roll... Now you then could use `ref` or `out` parameters, but why. The caller should know how many dice they want to roll and expect you to return the value for each dice roll. So you can return an `int[]` as the result as.

```
 int[] rollDice(int diceCount)
 {
    if(diceCount <= 0 || diceCount > 3)
         throw new ArgumentException("Dice must be between 1 to 3");

    int[] result = new int[diceCount];


   return result;
 }
```

Now we will return an `int[]` of the amount of dice requested to roll within the 1 - 3 parameter guideline. All that is missing is the actual dice roll. Now my suggestion is using a static Random (or an even better random solution) and just fill the result array with the roll results. Hope this helps..

Edit missed that part of up-to 3 dice but any not rolled is zero. Well that is easy to handle. Ensure the dice count is greater or equal to 1 and calculate the rest as zeros as.

```
int[] rollDice(int diceCount)
   {
       if(diceCount <= 0)
           throw new ArgumentException("Dice must be at least 1");

        int[] result = new int[diceCount];
        for(int i=0;i<diceCount;i++)
        {
            if(i < 3)
            {
                //Roll die...
                result[i] = 1;//Roll the die (not 1, use a random)
            }
            else
            {
                result[i] = 0;
            }
      }

      return result;
    }
```

Comment: The spec specifically says to return a zero for each die not rolled.

Comment: @Rawling True, but I for one would push back on that requirement and attempt to have it changed.  It's just not a sensible behavior.

Comment: The comment box says to avoid comments like "thank you", Well thank you anyway!!

Comment: @PatrickLuchies your welcome. hope we didnt spoil the assignment

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a function `C#` has the option of either returning a value of its return type or throw an exception. To my understanding, this property must also be decidable based on a static code analysis; apparently this is not the case four your implementation. You could use the signature

```
void RollDice(int NumberOfRolls, ref int Result1, ref int Result2, ref int Result3)
```

for your method and assign `Result1` to `Result3` only if a roll for the dice is desired. Alternatively, you could use the signature

```
int[] RollDice(int NumberofRolls)
```

to achieve your goal.

Comment: That's a pretty terrible method signature, and would make for an extraordinarily annoying to use method to accomplish this goal.

Comment: @Servy I totally agree, but apparently this approach was given as a hint in the original formulation.

Comment: That doesn't mean you should listen to it.  Since it's an actively harmful hint, ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a compile error because your method doesn't return a value (in this case an int) in all cases or in every code path. If we are strictly going to use your existing method and make it compile, you could use a variable which will hold the value the method should return and then return that at the end of the method, something like:

```
int moredice()
{
    Random rndom = new Random();
    var nummer = rndom.Next(1, 6);
    Boolean[] Barr = { true, false, true, false, true, false };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (Barr[nummer] == true)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            nummer = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    return nummer;
}
```

I believe this still preserves your original intention on what the method should do but now it will compile.

Here is my suggested solution to your problem:

```
static void RollDice(uint numberOfRolls, out int[] results)
{
    //Set a constant value defining the max no. of rolls
    const int maxRolls = 3;

    //Though not specified, ideally you'd want to notify the user if the input exceeds the max no. of dice rolls
    if (numberOfRolls > maxRolls)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("No. of rolls must be not more than {0}", maxRolls));
    }

    //Initialize the array of integer which holds the results (based on maxRolls)
    //This becomes results[0] = 0, results[1] = 0, results[2] = 0
    //The int data type has the default value of 0, so we can just use this default as is
    results = new int[maxRolls];

    const int minDiceValue = 1, maxDiceValue = 6;

    var rand = new Random();
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfRolls; i++)
    {
        //Populate the results array with a random value from 1 to 6
        //Note that I'm adding '1' to the max value parameter since it is exclusive not inclusive of the range
        results[i] = rand.Next(minDiceValue, maxDiceValue + 1);
    }
}
```

You can then call the method like so:

```
static void Main()
{   
    //Pass the no. of dice rolls and an array of integer which holds the results
    //Note that you can't pass a value less than zero in the first parameter since we used uint instead of int
    //Also note that you can pass an uninitialized array since we are using the out keyword
    //I'll leave knowing the difference between the different data types, out/ref keywords to you
    int[] results;  
    RollDice(3, out results);

    for (var i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dice Roll #{0}: {1}", i + 1, results[i]);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
static void Main()
{
    int diceRoll;
    int roll1 = 0;
    int roll2 = 0;
    int roll3 = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of dice to roll");
    diceRoll = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    RollDice(ref diceRoll, ref roll1, ref roll2, ref roll3);
    Console.WriteLine("Your dice rolled:");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{3}", diceRoll, roll1, roll2, roll3
}

static void RollDice(ref int diceRoll, ref int roll1, ref int roll2, ref int roll3)
{
    Random die = new Random();
    if (diceRoll == 1)
    {
        roll1 = die.Next(1, 7);
    }
    else if (diceRoll == 2)
    {
        roll1 = die.Next(1, 7);
        roll2 = die.Next(1, 7);
    }
    else if (diceRoll >= 3)
    {
        roll1 = die.Next(1, 7);
        roll2 = die.Next(1, 7);
        roll3 = die.Next(1, 7);
    }
    else
    {
        //You probably typed 0 since you got here without crashing the program
    }
}
```

This kind of shows you how to pass refs to a method.

I might create a new random 1-6 for rolled dice, and leave the unrolled one as 0. anything you do to the variables inside the method will be reflected on the variables outside the method. The ref passes the variables actual address so it replaces it.

Comment: It doesn't explain the issue that the op is having, however

Comment: He asked for a slight push in the right direction, he says in his question, he needs to pass 4 parameters as a ref or an out. He is not on the right track with what he wrote

Comment: @Scriven No, his requirements say no such thing, and doing that would also be a pretty terrible idea, as it would make for a pretty terrible method.

Comment: "You will have to pass four parameters and either use the out or ref keyword"

Comment: Meh I read it as Pass four parameters AND
use either out or ref or an array.

And I thought if I have to use 4 parameters I might as well use ref, because for all I know this assignment is supposed to get the student used to passing parameters.

But either way you @Servy, seem kind of angry. The answer was still right.